# What's the correct punctuation for что in "Ты что с ума сошел?"?

Tags: пунктуация

What's the correct punctuation in the following usage of что:

> - Ты что с ума сошел?
> - Он что сам не может справиться?
> - Я что дура?

Should there be a comma, a dash or something else?

Also, as additional bonus questions

> - What part of speech is что here?
> - Is there a special name/term for this usage?

Comment: Armen, this is close to Armenian `xom` (sorry, I have not armenian letters here): 'Xom du gizh ches' :)))

Comment: @shabunc: I know what что means here :) I was just asking about the punctuation and grammar aspect :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess in this context "что" is extremely close to [interrogative particle](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category%3aRussian_interrogative_particles).

In Polish, as well as in Ukrainian there [exists](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/czy) `czy` (`чи`), that interrogative particle is used in yes-no questions. For example, phrase, provided in above-mentioned link "Czy ten pan jest z Anglii?", can be translated "Этот господин из Англии" as well as it can be translated "Этот господин [он] что, из Англии"? Also, this can be translated with another interrogative particle, `ли`:
"Этот господин из Англии ли"?

Let's look close to your examples, actually, all of them can be replaced by following forms:

- Ты с ума сошёл что ли?
- Я дура что ли?
- Он сам не может справиться что ли? (Or - он, что ли, сам не может справиться?)

`Что ли` is, by the way, yet another form of interrogative particle.

It's just that in Russian this  form with "что" is definitely have some stylistical connotations. Compare:

> "Хочешь булочку?"

and

> "Ты что, хочешь булочку"?

In second case one who asks this question is assuming that the answer most probably will be affirmative. Also, such "что"-questions is a bit pathetical ("Мы что же это, Родину предадим?").

As for punctuation, stick with comma after "что", but keep in mind that in some cases when you want to separate second part more clearly, you can use dash as well. In some phrases, especially short ones, you can omit comma at all, no one will judge you hard. By doing this you can convey liveliness of colloquial speech.

Answer (score 4):

These are clarification questions:

*Ты что, с ума сошел?
Он что, сам не может справиться?
Я что, дура?*

*Что* is interrogative pronoun.

Comment: Interrogative pronoun is in phrases like "Что ты делаешь?", "Что ты хочешь?" and so on. This is a little bit different.

Comment: I don't believe these are clarification questions. In all these cases the one clearly implies that the other party is wrong. I would rather call this rhetorical questions.

Answer (score 3):

According to paragraph 158 of Russian orthography and punctuation rules as of 1956:

> Запятая ставится после слов **да**, **конечно** и т. п., обозначающих
> утверждение, после **нет**, обозначающего отрицание, после **как же**, **что же**,
> обозначающих подтверждение, согласие и т. п., после **что**, обозначающего
> вопрос, если эти слова тесно связаны с непосредственно следующим за
> ними предложением, раскрывающим их конкретный смысл, например:
>
> *Да, я тот несчастный, которого ваш отец лишил куска хлеба, выгнал из
> отеческого дома и послал грабить на больших дорогах (Пушкин).*
>
> *— А вы были в Москве, доктор?
> — Да, я имел там некоторую практику (Лермонтов).*
>
> *Нет, не дряхлому Востоку покорить меня (Лермонтов).*
>
> *— Вы помните Катюшу у тётушки Марии Ивановны?
> — Как же, я её шить учила (Л. Толстой).*
>
> *— Что, испугался давеча? — спросил отец, толкнув меня (М. Горький).*

So that correct punctuation is:

> Ты что, с ума сошел?
>
> Он что, сам не может справиться?
>
> Я что, дура?

Answer (score 0):

Well all i can say (as a native speaker) is that this comma is put here to help the reader to understand the intonation, because the meaning of this sentence is clear.

Comment: Welcome to Russian Language and Usage Beta! Usually we prefer longer and more elaborated answers on short answers. If you can improve your answer by adding detail, context, examples, and backing up with references, this would increase your answer's quality. Also, try to answer the question, which is why which one to choose. Poor answers risk being down-voted and subsequently removed.